# Generate cryptocurrency addresses on server

Tags: currencies, address-generation

I want to generate cryptocurrency addresses (e.g. for top 10 cryptocurrencies on CoinMarketCap) on my server and be able to send transactions when deposit arrives. Can I do that with CLIs or there is another/better way to do that? Or maybe there is a service that is suitable for cryptocurrency address generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you will need a bitcoin core installed and fully synced and after you have that, you can use this php library to help you (i used this before i recommended to you):

https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any library that supports BTC, BTH, ETH and other coins from Top 10?

Comment: Yes this can also do it as long as the coin has json-rpc. but cons is that you will need all core synced which takes up alot of disk space